# Good names for flipped versions of `lt`, `lte`, `gt`, and `gte`?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I've been working for some time on a Javascript FP library called **[Ramda](https://github.com/ramda/ramda)**, and I'm having a slight problem with naming things.  (You've heard the old line, right?  "There are only two hard problems in Computer Science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.")

In this library, (almost) every function of more than one parameter is automatically curried.  And this works well for most use-cases.  But there are some issues with a few functions which are non-commutative binary operators.  The issue is that the English names often tend to imply something different than what happens when currying is applied.  For example,

```
var div10 = divide(10);
```

*sounds* like it should be a function that divides its parameter by 10.  But in fact it divides its parameter **into** 10, which is pretty clear if you look at the definition:

```
var divide = curry(function(a, b) {
    return a / b;
});
```

So instead the expected:

```
div10(50); //=> 5 // NO!!
```

In fact, you get

```
div10(50); //=> 0.2 // Correct, but surprising!
```

We handle this by documenting the difference from people's possible expectations, and creating `divideBy`, which is just `flip(divide)` and `subtractN`, which is `flip(subtract)`.  But we haven't found a good equivalent for functions such as `lt`:

```
R.lt = curry(function(a, b) { 
    return a < b;
});
```

or its cousins `lte`, `gt`, and `gte`.

My own intuition would be that

```
map(lt(5), [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]); 
//=> [false, false, false, false, true, true, false]
```

But of course, it actually returns

```
//=> [true, true, true, false, false, false, true]
```

So I'd like to do the same document-and-point-to-alternate-name routine for `lt` and its ilk.  But I haven't been able to find a good name.  The only real candidate has been `ltVal` and that doesn't really work when called with both arguments.   We did **[discuss this issue](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/175)**, but had no good conclusions.

Have others dealt with this and come up with good solutions?  Or even if not, any good suggestions for a name for the flipped versions of these functions?

---

**Update**

Someone suggested that this be closed because 'unclear what you were asking', and I guess the question really *was* lost a bit in the explanation.  The simple question is:

What would be a good, intuitive name for a flipped version of `lt`?

Comment: In composition I put the "receiver" at the end, so `div = curry (x, y) => y / x`. This is the behavior I would expect by default.

Comment: Surely the opposite of `lt` is `gte`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: pretty sure he's asking about the difference between `lt` and `flip(lt)` given that `lt` is curried, `lt(10)(5)` isn't the same as `flip(lt)(10)(5)`

Comment: @elclanrs: According to the OP's final example, it's simply doing a `gte` rather than the "expected" `lt`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Oh I see what you mean, because `gt = flip(lt)`

Comment: Yes, `flip(lt)(5)` is certainly equivalent to `gte(5)`.  But the point is when I want readable code, I would like it to read something that looks like "is less than 5".  But "`gte(5)`" does not read that way to me.  It's all about readability and expectations.  The functionality is all there.

Comment: @elclanrs: all our functions are automatically curried, and it also would feel strange (to me at least) for `divide(20, 10) //=> .5`.  That's why in our code these binary operators are applied left-to-right.  It's not an issue of course for the commutative ones, but these others are problematic.

Comment: Not a name suggestion, but Haskell/Scala solve this problem with sections/place holders: (>2) or _ > 2. I don't know if something like that is doable in JS

Comment: @bmaderbacher: This is where everyone gets Haskell-envy!  There's really nothing equivalent in JS.  There's certainly no notion of infix functions, that's for sure.

Comment: @ScottSauyet No, `flip(lt)(5)` is not equivalent to `gte(5)`. It is equivalent to `gt(5)`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The opposite of `lt` is `gt` and not `gte`.

Comment: @AaditMShah - Depends what you mean by "opposite".  In the OP's example, the behaviour he wants is `gte`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No. I am pretty sure that the OP wants `gt` and not `gte`. See the example he gave, "My own intuition would be that `map(lt(5), [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9])` return `[false, false, false, false, true, true, false]`." If the OP wanted `gte` then `lt(5)(5)` would be `true` and not `false`. But it isn't. Hence, the OP wants `gt` and not `gte`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: The converse of `lt` is `gte`, but, @AaditMShah is quite right that what I wanted here was `gt`, which clearly equates to`flip(lt)`.  In any case, we did try for a short time to implement something like the suggestion made here.  It didn't work well for us, but it lead nonetheless to some very interesting changes in our library.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all, kudos on the functional programming library that you are maintaining. I've always wanted to write one myself, but I've never found the time to do so.

Considering the fact that you are writing a functional programming library I'm going to assume that you know about Haskell. In Haskell we have functions and operators. Functions are always prefix. Operators are always infix.

Functions in Haskell can be converted into operators using backticks. For example `div 6 3` can be written as `` 6 `div` 3 ``. Similarly operators can be converted into functions using parentheses. For example `2 < 3` can be written as `(<) 2 3`.

Operators can also be partially applied using sections. There are two types of sections: left sections (e.g. `(2 <)` and `` (6 `div`) ``) and right sections (e.g. `(< 3)` and `` (`div` 3) ``). Left sections are translated as follows: `(2 <)` becomes `(<) 2`. Right sections: `(< 3)` becomes `flip (<) 3`.

---

In JavaScript we only have functions. There is no *“good”* way to create operators in JavaScript. You can write code like `(2).lt(3)`, but in my humble opinion it is uncouth and I would strongly advise against writing code like that.

So trivially we can write normal functions and operators as functions:

```
div(6, 3) // normal function: div 6 3
lt(2, 3) // operator as a function: (<) 2 3
```

Writing and implementing infix operators in JavaScript is a pain. Hence we won't have the following:

```
(6).div(3) // function as an operator: 6 `div` 3
(2).lt(3) // normal operator: 2 < 3
```

However sections are important. Let's start with the right section:

```
div(3) // right section: (`div` 3)
lt(3) // right section: (< 3)
```

When I see `div(3)` I would expect it to be a right section (i.e. it should behave as `` (`div` 3) ``). Hence, according to the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), this is the way it should be implemented.

Now comes the question of left sections. If `div(3)` is a right section then what should a left section look like? In my humble opinion it should look like this:

```
div(6, _) // left section: (6 `div`)
lt(2, _) // left section: (2 <)
```

To me this reads as *“divide 6 by something”* and *“is 2 lesser than something?”* I prefer this way because it is explicit. According to [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), *“Explicit is better than implicit.”*

---

So how does this affect existing code? For example, consider the `filter` function. To filter the odd numbers in a list we would write `filter(odd, list)`. For such a function does currying work as expected? For example, how would we write a `filterOdd` function?

```
var filterOdd = filter(odd);    // expected solution
var filterOdd = filter(odd, _); // left section, astonished?
```

According to the principle of least astonishment it should simply be `filter(odd)`. The `filter` function is not meant to be used as an operator. Hence the programmer should not be forced to use it as a left section. There should be a clear distinction between functions and *“function operators”*.

Fortunately distinguishing between functions and function operators is pretty intuitive. For example, the `filter` function is clearly not a function operator:

```hs
filter odd list -- filter the odd numbers from the list; makes sense
odd `filter` list -- odd filter of list? huh?
```

On the other hand the `elem` function is clearly a function operator:

```hs
list `elem` n -- element n of the list; makes sense
elem list n -- element list, n? huh?
```

It's important to note that this distinction is only possible because functions and function operators are mutually exclusive. It stands to reason that given a function it may either be a normal function or else a function operator, but not both.

---

It's interesting to note that given a binary function if you `flip` its arguments then it becomes a binary operator and vice versa. For example consider the flipped variants of `filter` and `elem`:

```hs
list `filter` odd -- now filter makes sense an an operator
elem n list -- now elem makes sense as a function
```

In fact this could be generalized for any n-arity function were n is greater than 1. You see, every function has a primary argument. Trivially, for unary functions this distinction is irrelevant. However for non-unary functions this distinction is important.

1. If the primary argument of the function comes at the end of the argument list then the function is a normal function (e.g. `filter odd list` where `list` is the primary argument). Having the primary argument at the end of the list is necessary for function composition.
2. If the primary argument of the function comes at the beginning of the argument list then the function is a function operator (e.g. `` list `elem` n `` where `list` is the primary argument).
3. Operators are analogous to methods in OOP and the primary argument is analogous to the object of the method. For example `` list `elem` n `` would be written as `list.elem(n)` in OOP. Chaining methods in OOP is analogous to function composition chains in FP<sup>[1]</sup>.
4. The primary argument of the function may only be either at the beginning or at the end of the argument list. It wouldn't make sense for it to be anywhere else. This property is vacuously true for binary functions. Hence flipping binary functions makes them operators and vice-versa.
5. The rest of the arguments along with the function form an indivisible atom called the stem of the argument list. For example in `filter odd list` the stem is `filter odd`. In `` list `elem` n `` the stem is `` (`elem` n) ``.
6. The order and the elements of the stem must remain unchanged for the expression to make sense. This is why `` odd `filter` list `` and `elem list n` don't make any sense. However `` list `filter` odd `` and `elem n list` make sense because the stem is unchanged.

---

Coming back to the main topic, since functions and function operators are mutually exclusive you could simply treat function operators differently than the way you treat normal functions.

We want operators to have the following behavior:

```
div(6, 3) // normal operator: 6 `div` 3
div(6, _) // left section: (6 `div`)
div(3)    // right section: (`div` 3)
```

We want to define operators as follows:

```
var div = op(function (a, b) {
    return a / b;
});
```

The definition of the `op` function is simple:

```
function op(f) {
    var length = f.length, _; // we want underscore to be undefined
    if (length < 2) throw new Error("Expected binary function.");
    var left = R.curry(f), right = R.curry(R.flip(f));

    return function (a, b) {
        switch (arguments.length) {
        case 0: throw new Error("No arguments.");
        case 1: return right(a);
        case 2: if (b === _) return left(a);
        default: return left.apply(null, arguments);
        }
    };
}
```

The `op` function is similar to using backticks to convert a function into a operator in Haskell. Hence you could add it as a standard library function for Ramda. Also mention in the docs that the primary argument of an operator should be the first argument (i.e. it should look like OOP, not FP).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> On a side note it would be awesome if Ramda allowed you to compose functions as though it was chaining methods in regular JavaScript (e.g. `foo(a, b).bar(c)` instead of `compose(bar(c), foo(a, b))`). It's difficult, but doable.

Comment: This is a **fantastic** answer!  It not only gives a potential solution to my issue (one I'll have to take up with the team before implementing) but also offers some excellent insight into the general problem.  Thank you very much.

Comment: We probably won't be doing anything like method chaining in Ramda.  Certainly we won't anytime soon.  In a very real sense I'm trying to articulate in a wiki entry or blog post coming soon, the whole point of the library is to enable the functional composition style that's been difficult to do in JS.  I think the method chaining would just be a distraction at the moment.  OTOH, we always welcome pull requests!

Comment: Such an excellent answer. Thanks for taking the time to explain it.

Comment: It was as if that answer was lifted right out of some classic FP book. Thank you for the depth and clarity of your explanation.

Comment: (self promotion) I totally agree with the reasoning around argument order. So I made [fnuc](https://github.com/algesten/fnuc) which curries reverse and composing by chaining.

Comment: infix functions and left/right section in JS: `$ = (x, f, y) => f(x) (y); $_ = (x, f) => f(x); _$ = (f, y) => x => f(x) (y); sub = x => y => x - y; $(2, sub, 3); $_(2, sub) (3); _$(sub, 3) (2)`. As you can see I prefer visual names (`$`, `$_`, `_$`) to textual ones in this case. Unfortunately, still not as concise as in Haskell :(

Answer (score 2):

We all know that naming in programming is serious business, particularly when it comes to functions in curried form. It is a valid solution to handle this issue with a programmatic approach as Aadit did in his response. However, I see two issues with his implementation:

- it introduces function operators with left/right sections in Javascript, which are not part of the language
- it requires a hideous placeholder or `undefined` hack to achieve that

Javascript has no curried operators and thus no left or right sections. An idiomatic Javascript solution should consider that.

## The cause of the problem

Curried functions don't have a notion of arity, because every function invocation requires exactly one argument. You can either partially or completely apply curried functions without any helpers:

```
const add = y => x => x + y;

const add2 = add(2); // partial application

add(2)(3); // complete application
```

Usually the last argument of a function is its primarily one, because it is passed through function compositions (similar to objects that allow method chaining). Consequently when you partially apply a function, you want to pass its initial arguments:

```
const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));

const map = f => xs => xs.map(x => f(x));

const inc = x => x + 1;

const sqr = x => x * x;


comp(map(inc)) (map(sqr)) ([1,2,3]); // [2,5,10]
```

Operator functions are special in this regard. They are binary functions that reduce their two arguments to a single return value. Since not every operator is commutative (a - b !== b - a) the argument order matters. For this reason operator functions don't have a primarily argument. But people are accustomed to read expressions with them in a certain way depending on the type of application:

```
const concat = y => xs => xs.concat(y);

const sub = y => x => x - y;


// partial application:

const concat4 = concat(4);

const sub4 = sub(4);

concat4([1,2,3]); // [1,2,3,4] - OK

sub4(3); // -1 - OK


// complete application:

concat([1,2,3]) (4); // [4,1,2,3] - ouch!

sub(4) (3); // -1 - ouch!
```

We defined `concat` and `sub` with flipped arguments, so that partial application works as expected. This evidently doesn't apply to complete application though.

## A manual solution

```
const flip = f => y => x => f(x) (y);

const concat_ = flip(concat);

const sub_ = flip(sub);


concat_(xs) (4); // [1,2,3,4] - OK

sub_(4) (3); // 1 - OK
```

`concat_` and `sub_` correspond to left sections in Haskell. Please note that function operators like `add` or `lt` don't need a left section version because the former are commutative and the latter are predicates, which have logical counterparts:

```
const comp2 = f => g => x => y => f(g(x) (y));

const map = f => xs => xs.map(x => f(x));

const flip = f => y => x => f(x) (y);

const not = x => !x;

const notf2 = comp2(not);


const lt = y => x => x < y;

const gt = flip(lt);

const lte = notf2(gt);

const gte = notf2(lt);


map(lt(5)) ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]);
// [false, false, false, false, true, true, false]

map(gte(5)) ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]);
// [true, true, true, true, false, false, true]
```

---

## Conclusion

We should solve this naming issue rather with a naming convention then with a programmatic solution which extends Javascript in a non-idiomatic way. Naming conventions are not ideal...well, just like Javascript.

Comment: In the two years since I asked this question, Ramda has tried several approaches at this problem, included a very brief attempt at Aadit's solution.  Although we still haven't fully done it, it seems that we've come to a reluctant agreement with your conclusion: there's nothing really better than a naming convention here.  Ours will probably be a bit different from yours, but it's the same idea.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Scott This curry-naming-thingy is causing me problems for months. I'm glad to hear that I am not alone with it :D