# Bind only second argument to javascript function

Tags: javascript, currying

```
var add = function(a, b) {

    return a + b;
}
var addOne =add.bind(null,1);
var result = addOne(4);
console.log(result);
```

Here the binded value of a is 1 and b is 4.

How to assign the binding value i.e)1 to the second argument of the function without using spread operator(...)

Comment: can you post your entire code ??

Comment: You'd have to write your own version of `.bind()`. The only tool I've ever seen that could do this was the [functional.js](http://functionaljs.com/) library, but that API does not seem to be there anymore. It's an unusual thing to do.

Comment: have you looked at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699493/javascript-partially-applied-function-how-to-bind-only-the-2nd-parameter

Comment: "_binding value_ " is somewhat confusing here. `bind` sets the `this` value used in the function, the rest of the arguments passed to `bind` are ... well, arguments to the function to call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a swap function with binding the final function.

```js
var add = function (a, b) { console.log(a, b); return a + b; },
    swap = function (a, b) { return this(b, a); },
    addOne = swap.bind(add, 1),
    result = addOne(4);

console.log(result);
```

With decorator, as [georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg) suggested.

```js
var add = function (a, b) { console.log(a, b); return a + b; },
    swap = function (f) { return function (b, a) { return f.call(this, a, b) }; },
    addOne = swap(add).bind(null, 1),
    result = addOne(4);

console.log(result);
```

You could use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object for reordering the parameters.

```js
var add = function (a, b, c, d, e) {
        console.log(a, b, c, d, e);
        return a + b + c + d + e;
    },
    swap = function (f) {
        return function () { 
            var arg = Array.apply(null, arguments);
            return f.apply(this, [arg.pop()].concat(arg));
        };
    },
    four = swap(add).bind(null, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    result = four(1);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I'd make `swap` a decorator, so it could be used like `swap(add).bind(...)`.

Comment: What if I have 'n' number of arguments and have to bind the values except the first argument

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way

```
var add = function(x){
    return function(y){
        return x+y;
    }
}

add(2)(3); // gives 5
var add5 = add(5);
add5(10); // gives 15
```

here add5() would set x = 5 for the function

Answer (score 0):

This will help you what you need

```
var add = function(a) {
    return function(b) {
        return a + b;
    };
}
var addOne = add(1);
var result = addOne(4);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
function add (n) {
    var func = function (x) {
        if(typeof x==="undefined"){
           x=0;
        }
        return add (n + x);
    };

    func.valueOf = func.toString = function () {
        return n;
    };

    return func;
}
console.log(+add(1)(2));
console.log(+add(1)(2)(3));
console.log(+add(1)(2)(5)(8));
```