# How to unshift extra argument rather than push it when I call already bound function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arguments, bind

```
var bound = async.bind({},'hello','world');
bound.call({},resolve,reject);

function async(){
  console.log(arguments) //0:'hello', 1:'world', 2:resolve, 3:reject
  //what I expect: 0:resolve, 1:reject, 2:'hello', 3:'world'
}
function resolve(){}
function reject(){}
```

When I have a function that is already bound with some arguments, and then I use `.call` with extra arguments, these extra arguments are **pushed** *(added to the end)* into the `arguments` object of this function.

Is it any possibility, to **unshift** *(add to the beginning)* these extra arguments to the `arguments` object in this case when the function is already bound with some arguments?

Comment: @NinaScholz no it's not, `log: ["hello", "world", ƒ, ƒ]` I know that it is the default behaviour of `.call`, but I'm looking for some solution to change the order of arguments.

Comment: you may have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485140/bind-only-second-argument-to-javascript-function

Comment: Btw, you should never need to pass promise `resolve` and `reject` functions around. Have `async` return a self-created promise instead of taking callbacks. You might want to ask a new question about your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a different approach for binding with a function for swapping the arguments.

```js
function resolve() {}
function reject() {}

function async() {
    console.log(arguments);
}

function swap(a, b, c, d) {
    return this(c, d, a, b);
}

var bound = swap.bind(async, 'hello', 'world');

bound.call({}, resolve, reject);
```

Comment: the problem is that I haven't got the access to the arguments of bound function, except Chrome's `[[BoundArgs]]` function's property what is not a good solution. I've got only the access to **already bound** function, then I want to `.call` it with extra arguments, so these extra arguments were placed at the beginning of `arguments` object.